# Se me muestran registros ajenos en una consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Compañeros, necesito una ayuda rápida. Estoy haciendo un buscador en tiempo real de unos productos. Los productos están divididos por programas (id_programa), pero al momento de hacer la consulta (que la estoy probando por PHPMyAdmin), me muestra todos los resultados aunque el otro producto pertenezca a otro programa.

La consulta es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_prog=1 AND sub_categoria_prod='Aceites' 
AND sibol_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' OR nombre_prod LIKE '%Aceite%'
```

Repito: Hay 2 (sub_categoria_prod) Aceites en el programa 1, y un (sub_categoria_prod) Aceites en el programa 2, pero la consulta me muestra los 3 (sub_categoria_prod) Aceites, cuando necesito que se me muestre sólo el primero.

Se me meustra esta información, pero necesito que **me muestre sólo los dos primeros (los que están resaltados)**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la cláusula web la estás planteado mal.
Lo que me das a entender es que quieres esto:

- Que esté en la subcategoría "Aceites".
- Que el id del programa sea "1".
- Que el nombre sea como "Aceite" o, en su defecto, el sibol_prod sea como "Aceite".

En ese caso, la cláusula where debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```
WHERE 
    sub_categoria_prod='Aceites' 
    AND 
    id_prog=1 
    AND
    (nombre_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' OR sibol_prod LIKE '%Aceite%')
```

EDIT:

Así consigues que:

Si se cumple -> sub_categoria_prod='Aceites'

Y si se cumple -> id_prog = 1

Y si se cumple -> nombre prod Ó sibol_prod sea como "%aceite".

Comment: Perfecto. Muchísimas gracias. Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Entonces, eso significa que hay que aislarlos entre paréntesis. (?)

Comment: Sí, te lo edito en la respuesta para explicártelo.

Comment: Si te resuelve la consulta, por favor, marca la respuesta como válida ;)

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar solo un resultado en caso de ser el primero limita la consulta quedando de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_prog=1 AND sub_categoria_prod='Aceites' 
AND sibol_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' OR nombre_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' AND categoria_prod = "Ingredientes"
```

Si lo que buscas el el ultimo elemento solo deberás de ordene de manera descendente y volver a limitar a uno para mostrar el ultimo. Espero haber resulto tu duda.

Comment: No, no me funciona, porque necesito que me muestre todos los aceites que hay en el programa 1, no que me muestre sólo 1, pero sin que se me muestre el aceite del otro programa.

Comment: Puedes agregar una muestra de la tabla con los datos y como debería de salir el resultado?

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta para adjuntar una imagen.

Comment: Con los datos que muestras me parece que falta agregar el campo "Categoria_prod" para que se muestren solamente los que me indicas en la imagen, te dejo en la respuesta como debería de quedar la consulta.

Comment: No, esa categoria_prod='ihk', es sólo un ejemplo. La consulta original es lo que necesito modificar.

Answer (score 0):

De hecho, ya pude resolver pregunta. xD
El problema, es que al usar un OR, casi cuenta como una consulta nueva, por lo que el límite se debe volver a poner, así que simplemente modifiqué y quedó así.

```
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE sub_categoria_prod='Aceites' AND id_prog=1 
AND nombre_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' OR sibol_prod LIKE '%Aceite%' AND id_prog=1
```

Igual, muchas gracias por intentar ayudarme.

Comment: Así no debes hacerlo. Esa consulta te va a fallar. Te publico una respuesta.